# How to filter the records in URL based on the values present inside them?

Tags: http, https, servicenow

I Have three fields parent,type,child. How do i filter the records inside the field "type" in URL. for example there is one value inside "type" field called "Used By" and i want only records with the type "Used by".

i am trying with the below method

&sysparm_query=typeISUsed%20by

doing this i am getting huge records with all the types.instead of filtering only "Used by" type

and also how do i combine if i want to filter multiple record value like "Used by", "Depends On", "Managed by","Connected by".

Comment: By &type=Used%20by, I was able to query records with the type "Used by". but i am not able to query with the combination of values. looking for the solution to combine and query records with these types "Used by", "Depends On", "Managed by","Connected by"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution with this following method below.

For Each relationship type inside ServiceNow, There is a SYS ID. for example i have two SYS ID's
1a9cb166f1571100a92eb60da2bce5c5 and 60bc4e22c0a8010e01f074cbe6bd73c3

By putting sysparm_query=type=1a9cb166f1571100a92eb60da2bce5c5^ORtype=60bc4e22c0a8010e01f074cbe6bd73c3 inside the URL, i was able to combine the filters and get records only related to these SYS ID's.

Another easy method is first put a filters in Service now for all the relationship types.
Then copy the query URL and append "sysparm_query=" to the URL.